# NSPredicate with Multiple Condition - Execute second condition based on first condition

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate

I need to fetch data from Core data, for that , I need to check Condition1 and Condition 2 using **NSPredicate**.
But I only need to check the condition 2 once condition 1 satisfied .
Any one please help me to achieve this scenario ?

Logic

```
If (Condition1 == true)
{
     if(Condition2 == True)
        {
         }
    else
       {
      //Code
       }
}
else
{
//codes
}
```

Please help me to achieve this scenario using **NSPredicate**.

Comment: So, if `(condition1 == true) && (condition2 == true)`, some code; if `(condition1 == true) && (condition2 == false)`, some code; `if (condition1 == false) && (condition2 == true/false)`, some code right?

Comment: `NSPredicate` can be used to fetch or filter data. It can't execute code.

Comment: @Willeke, well there's `predicateWithBlock:` but I take your meaning.

Comment: I mean, you can't put `//Code` and `//codes` in a predicate.

Answer (score 1):

Just use an `AND` expression in your predicate format string. `NSPredicate` treats those as short-circuiting operators. That's implicit in this advice from the [Predicate Programming Guide: Using Predicates – Performance Considerations](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001794-SW2) section:

> You should structure compound predicates to minimize the amount of
>   work done. Regular expression matching in particular is an expensive
>   operation. In a compound predicate, you should therefore perform
>   simple tests before a regular expression […]:
>
> In the […] example, the regular expression [after an `OR`] **is evaluated only if the
>   first clause is false**.

(Emphasis added)

Comment: [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:] is the call I believe

Comment: @Alex, yes, that's the API for constructing the predicate programmatically, which is certainly valid. I think that, more often, predicates are constructed using `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"..."]`, in which case you'd just express it with an `AND` keyword in the string, which is what I was getting at.